# How to prevent Jersey from parsing numeric fields to string when parsing to json?

Tags: java, json, neo4j, jersey

I am building a Neo4J plugin using jersey-json to parse my POJO's to and from json. The problem is that my REST-services return numbers as strings.

If a POJO looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Item {
    private Integer value = 5;
    private int primitiveValue = 6;

    public Item() {}

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getPrimitiveValue() {
        return primitiveValue;
    }
}
```

I get a JSON-object looking like this:

```
{
    value: "5",
    primitiveValue: "6"
}
```

But I would expect it to be like this:

```
{
    value: 5,
    primitiveValue: 6
}
```

My resource looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/item")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getItem() {
    return Response.ok(new Item()).build();
}
```

My pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.project.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-extension</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <neo4j.version>2.2.0</neo4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>server-api</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Do you know how I could solve this problem? Why is the default behavior to parse numeric fields as strings?

**Solution**

After suggestion from Stefan Armbruster I added the following dependency to my pom, and all dependent jars to my `/plugins` folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And removed @XmlRootElement annotation from my POJO.

The difference from before is that I get all null-values in my response. With the @XmlRootElement annotation null-values are removed from the response, but I do not think this will be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your JAX-RS method to:

```
@GET
@Path("/item")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Item getItem() {
    return new Item();
}
```

If you get an error, amend <s>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson</s>  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.6.2 to your dependencies (and make sure that this jar is deployed to the `plugins` folder as well).

Comment: I did not get any errors, but it did not work for neither the primitive or the object type of the integers. More clean code however, so thank you!

Comment: If reference the wrong jar file. My answer has been updated. With the one mentioned I get `{"value":5,"primitiveValue":6}` as response.

Comment: I added jackson-jaxrs-json-provider to my pom and in my plugin-folder, but still get the same result.

In my plugins-folder I have the following jars now:
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.2.jar,
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.6.2.jar,
jackson-core-2.6.2.jar,
jersey-json-1.18.1.jar and
jersey-multipart-1.18.1.jar

What is different from your setup @Stefan Armbruster?

Comment: What version of Neo4J do you use?

Comment: I'm on 2.2.5. You basically need all (transitive) dependencies of jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.2.jar as well in `/plugins`.

Comment: I am using 2.2.0, could that be a problem? I added all dependencies to `/plugins`, so now I have the following jars: jersey-json-1.18.1.jar, jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.2.jar, jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.2.jar, jackson-jaxrs-base-2.6.2.jar, jackson-databind-2.6.2.jar, jackson-core-2.6.2.jar, jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar, stax-api-1.0-2.jar and activation-1.1.jar. I still get the same result, any other ideas?

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference, but don't have the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the Item class. If time allows I'll try to assemble a minimal setup and share by github.

Comment: `@XmlRootElement` did the trick. Thank you so much for your time, if we ever meet I will buy you a beer! :)